# Incompatibility between the `footnote` and `xcolor` packages

Tags: color, footnotes, incompatibility

The following code fails to build:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My first chapter}

\parbox{110mm}{
Here is a footnote\footnote{The footnote is here}.
Where is my footnote?
}

\end{document}
```

The error produced is:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<argument> ...@finalstrut \strutbox }\fn@endnote }

l.13 }
```

If I remove the `footnote` package, the footnote is not exported outside of the `parbox`, and I need the `xcolor` package to produce gray lettrines somewhere else in the document.

Is that a know bug? How can I circumvent it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Load `footnote` after `xcolor`. `footnote` contains a `\let\fn@endnote\color@endgroup`, this give the wrong result if `xcolor` hasn't been loaded yet (`xcolor`redefines `\color@endgroup`).

Comment: This is it! Wonderful!

Comment: `footnote` should do this better `\AtBeginDocument` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to combination of `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` to avoid having the footnote inside the `\parbox`. This works for you example, but is actually some technique the `footnote` package tries to avoid.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My first chapter}

\parbox{110mm}{
Here is a footnote\footnotemark.
Where is my footnote?
}
\footnotetext{The footnote is here}.

\end{document}
```

See also [this TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-footintab) which is more about footnotes in tables, but partially also applies here.

Comment: the footnote doesn't appear in the `\parbox` if I don't use the `footnote` package, it just doesn't appear at all.

Comment: the `\footnotemark`+`\footnotetext` does the trick. However, I'd really like to understand why `\footnote` won't play nice with `\xcolor`...

Answer (score 1):

use a minipage instead of the parbox:

```
\begin{minipage}{110mm}
Here is a footnote\footnote{The footnote is here}.
Where is my footnote?
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: That works, too. But the result is very different from what I expect. Using a `minipage`, the footnote text is put right at the end of the `minipage` (which makes sense), instead of being at the end of the page (where I would like it). @Martin's solution, on the other hand, allows to play the footnote text at the end of the page.