# Conflict between footnote and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, footnotes, minipage

It seems that the tikz package prevents the footnote package to function properly within a minipage.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage*}[t]{0.8\linewidth}
Here is some text\footnote{This is a footnote.}.
\end{minipage*}

\end{document}
```

Note that the minipage* environment is provided by the footnote package.

Using xelatex (TeXlive 2014), I get the following error:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<argument> ...@finalstrut \strutbox }\fn@endnote }

l.11 ...is some text\footnote{This is a footnote.}
```

Commenting out the tikz package and it works fine.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: The error is actually due to the `xcolor` package, which is loaded by `tikz`. See also [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15836/23765](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15827/incompatibility-between-the-footnote-and-xcolor-packages/15836#15836)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loading TikZ first seems to work?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{footnote}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage*}[t]{0.8\linewidth}
Here is some text\footnote{This is a footnote.}.
\end{minipage*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @zzjing Always worth a shot. Doesn't always work but, when it does.... And TikZ can be finnicky sometimes.